# Google Apps and my domain

Tags: google-workspace, domain

So, basically I'm considering buying a domain, just to use with Google Apps for now. Later I'm planning to use it for my website.
My question is: if I buy domain example.com and set up Google Apps on it (with [this form](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new)), will I be able to use it for anything else, like website? Or should I rather use Google Apps with some subdomain, like mail.example.com?

Also, will I have to verify ownership of this domain somehow? I don't have a hosting service yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use Google Apps for a domain and have a website on the same domain. I've done it. Plenty others do it too. Nothing precludes you from doing the same.

When you verify an apps account for a domain, you have a few choices. One is to upload a special text/html file to your web domain, which requires hosting to be in place.

Alternatively, you can add a special server header to your domain (not the hosting) via the domain registrar. This is probably appropriate for your case.